# Would a custom regex be the best way to match any given string in a list to any other string in another list?

Tags: python-3.x

Sorry, the question is clumsily worded, but it was the clearest way to express what I meant.  My goal is to get headlines from different sites, split the headlines up into their individual words, send those to a list, and do that once for each site.  Then, check the 2 lists against each other and find if there are words that match.  The thinking is that a significant story (like, the Turing Pharmaceutical) would ping a match, and would spit back the links to the stories with the matching words.  My idea was that this would get rid of the "noise" stories and be a way for me to figure out if a certain story was gaining traction in the media.

Anyway, I've written the first bit of code that would do something like this, but have run up against a wall in terms of matching *any* given word in one string with another.  I've gotten it to work if I search my **specific** words like Diesel and the VW story, but obviously that wouldn't work if I didn't want to check if a specific story was catching on.

Here's the code I've written thus far.  Any tips or comments would be much appreciated.  After googling, I think the best way to accomplish this would be with a regex but I'm not entirely convinced of that yet.

```
import feedparser

print('Collecting articles...')

reddit = feedparser.parse("https://www.reddit.com/r/news/.rss")

redditL = []

redditL.append(reddit.entries[0].title)
redditL.append(reddit.entries[1].title)
redditL.append(reddit.entries[2].title)
redditL = str(redditL)
redditSplit = str.split(redditL, None)
print(redditSplit)

nytimes = feedparser.parse("http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/HomePage.xml")

nytimesL = []
nytimesL.append(nytimes.entries[0].title)
nytimesL.append(nytimes.entries[1].title)
nytimesL.append(nytimes.entries[2].title)
nytimesL = str(nytimesL)
nytimesSplit = str.split(nytimesL, None)
print(nytimesSplit)

if ( # something in redditSplit) in nytimesSplit: # This is the part I need help with! 
    print('True!')
else:
    print('Keep trying...')
```

Comment: Why would you want a regex if you can just compare complete words (lower-cased if necessary)?

Comment: My problem is that I don't know how to compare any word in a string with a match in another string, not comparing specific words.  Sorry, I may have worded my question poorly.

Comment: You say you split the strings (headlines) into words already, and store those in a list. As far as I understand, you therefore have all the individual words already.

Comment: That's right, but I only know how to compare the lists 1:1 - by that I mean *all* the words in list 1 have to compare to the words in list 2. I'm not sure how to compare any words in the two lists in a way that would return the matching word.

Comment: But I would think that if you search around, you'll find a package that already can do all this: compare sentences by words and number of matches. It sounds like this is something that would be done a lot (in a variety of programming languages; surely Python will have its share of solutions).